Why is $\pi$ called pi.
I know e is called e because Euler named that as it is the first letter of exponential, but why is pi called pi?
I have tried googling searching, but I am unable to find the correct answer to this question. I know Archimedes discovered pi, but I know he didn't give the name to pi. Is it some other reason?

This is a good question for HSM SE.

You know e is called e because it is Euler's number? Citation?

sorry, I edited it. it is called e because of exponential

It's not really known why $e$ is called $e$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021988

Has this question really never been asked before on Math.SE?

As far as I know, no

See history of $\pi$ and William Oughtred used $\pi$ in Clavis Mathematicae (1631) but not for the ratio of the circumference to the diameter, merely for the circumference.
